# Open activity from shuffled list view

Tags: android

So basically I want this list view to be shuffled so it is always random. But each one needs to open up its own activity and be constant no matter where it is in the list view (so I'm pretty sure I can't use position.) So I tried using the (TextView) view).getText() and it isn't reading it as it does in the Toast. Any ideas?

```
public class Bands extends ListActivity{
int numBands;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



  final ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<String>();
    bands.add(new String("Band0"));
    bands.add(new String("Band1"));
    bands.add(new String("Band2"));

    Collections.shuffle(bands);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_list, bands));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      if( ((TextView) view).getText() == "Band0"){
            Intent i = new Intent(Bands.this, Audio.class);
            i.putExtra("Band", 0);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

  });
}
```

}

Anyone know a way to read the number order the shuffle creates? Cause that could be a way if someone knows how. Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making this change:

```
String text = ((TextView) view).getText();
if (text.equals("Band0") { 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question right, you need everytime the listview to be randomly populated. In your getView() where you set your strings from the list add this

Outside of getView

```
int remember = 0;
int[] rememberArray = new int[arraylist.size()-1]; //to store indexes that already has been drawn
```

Inside the `getView()`:

```
 Random gen= new Random()
    int randomPosition = gen.nextInt(arraylist.size()-1);
    rememberArray[remember]=randomPosition;
   remember++;
    for(int i =0; i <= rememberArray.length;i++){
    if(!remember==rememberArray[i])
    {
     arraylist.get(randomPosition);

    } else { //generate again, probably you can create method for this, and apply recursion

    }
    } //proceed with the rest of the getView()
```

This is not tested, I'm just giving you the idea.